# Initialize character arrays in class

Tags: c++, g++

When I compile the code below with g++ 4.8.2 I get an error.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class test {
public:
    void print() {
        cout << str << endl;
    }

private:
    char str[] = "123456789"; // error: initializer-string for array of chars
                              // is too long
};

int main() {
    char x[] = "987654321";
    cout << x << endl;

    test temp;
    temp.print();
}
```

Why did I get that error, what is the difference between `str` in class `test` and `x` in `main` function?

Comment: Are you trying to initialize an array of C-style strings? Or do you want to create a `char *` and assign it to a C string?

Comment: You know `char str[10] = "123456789";` _will_ compile , why ? Think !
Refer books !

Comment: Clang's error message for this code: `error: array bound cannot be deduced from an in-class initializer`. This limitation in C++ is a safety feature so that people don't accidentally change class layout without realizing it. Use an explicit bound.

Comment: @bames53 In this situation, clang's error message is much easier to understand than g++'s.

Comment: @birryree I want to initialize C string.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Inside your class, you have to *explicitly* specify the array size:

```
class test {
...
private:
    // If you really want a raw C-style char array...
    char str[10] = "123456789"; // 9 digits + NUL terminator
};
```

Or you can simply use a `std::string` (which I think is in general much better in C++ code than using raw C-style strings):

```
#include <string>
...

class test {
...
private:
    std::string str = "123456789"; 
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't have arrays of unknown size in structures/classes, you need to set an array size.

Or better yet, use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) for strings. It's what it's made for.

Answer (score 1):

I realised what you are asking and rewrite my entire reply.
You are not supposed to do you initialization in your class.
You only declare the variables/methods you want to use.
Only after that, you use your class to create objects.

Set the object's variable's value from then on.

**For example:**

```
class Test
{
   public:
        int num;    //You don't intialie value here
};

int main
{
       Test testObj();
       testObj.num = 100;
}
```

However, if you set the variables to private, you need to create a function in your class to access the class members. For exmaple `setNum()`

Alternatively, you can set the variables using the constructor, and insert it as parameter inputs during object creation.

```
class Test
{
   public:
        Test(int);  //Constructor
   private:
        int num;    //You don't intialie value here
};


Test::Test(int value)
{
    this -> num = value;
}

int main
{
    Test testObj(100); //set num to 100
}
```

If you want to access it using class member function, you can do this, but of course you have to define `setNum()` in your class first.

```
testObj.setNum(100);
```

I know you are asking about char[], but I am giving you example on int. That is not the problem in your code. Either int or char[], you should avoid declaring it directly in your class.
It seems like the main problem with your code is not whether you are using char[] or char*.
You should not initialize your values in your class.

Answer (score 0):

If you really know that you aren't going to modify the string and is always going to be the same, you can do this instead `const char *str = "123456789";`

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the size for char arrays. You can use a pointer instead if you don't know the size of the string or its size is dynamic.  If you do this, make sure you don't forget to add a null terminating character.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is

```
class foo {

    class y;  // Instance Variable

    void foo(){
        class x;  // Method Variable
        // use x and y
    }
}
```

An instance variable of a `char*` will work `char* x = "foobar"`. The compiler possibly allowing the method variable to be set to a `char[]` because the scope is limited. Am trying to lookup some literature to explain the different treatment.